# content_tag and html_safe not working as expected

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been given a string with html tags present, and my end goal is getting this to display in a p block with class 'style1' after applying the formatting present in the html tags:

```
<p class="style1">Text I want to display after applying formatting present in tags</p>
```

I've tried the following methods:

```
<%= content_tag :p, class: 'style1' do %>
  <%= question.html_safe %>
<% end %>


<p class="style1"><%= question.html_safe %></p>


<%= content_tag :p, question.html_safe, class: 'style1' %>
```

All 3 of these approaches leave me with:

```
<p class="style1"></p>
<p> Formatted question text </p>
```

I can get the text to appear in the correct paragraph div if I use strip_tags(question), however this obviously removes any styling before presenting the data.

Is there any way I can apply the styling, not have the tags show up, AND get the content in the correct p tag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the question string contain an additional `p` tag? If so, it won't work as you can't nest a `p` within a `p`.

Could you change the wrapper to a `div`? This should fix it. I.E.

```
<%= content_tag :div, question.html_safe, class: 'style1' %>
```

Or, strip any `p` tags from the question:

```
<%= content_tag :div, question.gsub(/<\/?p>/, '').strip.html_safe, class: 'style1' %>
```

Comment: Many, many, many thanks. - content included a P tag which apparently closes the first one

Comment: Great - you're welcome. Glad to help out! I've also added an alternative solution. You might want to refactor it a little, but if you prefer a single `p` tag without a wrapper, that should do it for you.